# Jersey 2.4 on Glassfish 4.0.1: How to inject context HttpServletRequest into ContainerRequestFilter?

Tags: servlets, glassfish, jersey, glassfish-4, jersey-2.0

Jersey 2.4 is able to inject HttpServletRequest: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1960

Glassfish 4.0.1 is bundled with Jersey 2.4: http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip

Opened bug at Glassfish:
https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20885

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest webRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        HttpSession session = webRequest.getSession();
        String user = (String)session.getAttribute("USER_ID");
    }
}
```

Glassfish 4.0.1 can not deploy this filter with the following exception:

```
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:302)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5946)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to create a Proxy for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest in proxiable scope org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped an error occured while creating the proxy
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2309)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ContextInjectionResolver.resolve(ContextInjectionResolver.java:104)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:803)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:832)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider$CdiFactory$2.getInstance(CdiComponentProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider$CdiFactory.provide(CdiComponentProvider.java:149)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:96)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:69)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2350)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllRankedProviders(Providers.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.getProcessingProviders(ApplicationHandler.java:617)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:410)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:302)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5946)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:302)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5946)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    Startup of context  failed due to previous errors]]

[glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00108] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1383814486801] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl is not visible from class loader
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5954)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:302)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5704)
    ... 50 more
    ]]
```

Comment: I've recently thrown out Glassfish and migrated to Wildfly. Now I'm happy that everything works stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the nightly version of 4.0.1 Glassfish on 12/25/2013.  I added a comment to the referenced [Glassfish ticket](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20885), but will look forward to this fix being pushed to any release.

Comment: Yes. It was fixed and works with the latest nightly build: http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/nightly/glassfish-4.0.1-b04-02_13_2014-ml.zip